# how make some elements of a column equal to each other?

Tags: r, dataframe

in the column

```
col
bus
car
walk 
train
citybus
metro
```

How I can make a new column whose is public transport instead of bus, train,citybus and metro?

i.e the output is

```
 col
 public transport
 car
 walk 
 public transport
 public transport
 public transport
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Is this a column in a data.frame? Is it a character vector or factor?

Comment: I got the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `replace` or `ifelse` would do

```
df$new_col <- replace(df$col, df$col %in% c("bus", "train", "citybus", "metro"), 
                      "public transport")

df
#      col          new_col
#1     bus public transport
#2     car              car
#3    walk             walk
#4   train public transport
#5 citybus public transport
#6   metro public transport
```

With `ifelse`

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$col %in% c("bus", "train", "citybus", "metro"), 
                    "public transport", df$col)
```

Or

```
df$new_col  <- df$col
df$new_col[df$col %in% c("bus", "train", "citybus", "metro")] <- "public transport"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col = c("bus", "car", "walk", "train", "citybus", 
"metro")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: why it gives me NA instead of public transport? in first method

Comment: @shere you might have `col` column as `factors`. Can you convert it to character `df$col <- as.character(df$col)` and then try it again?